# 404 page in nextjs app dir constantly refreshes with middleware

Tags: next.js, next-auth

within my project, we use the nextjs app directory
however with that, it does not include root 404 pages, so we instead use the pages/404.tsx file. in our middleware, it uses next-auth and vercel edge config to send the user to a maintenance page (if enabled on edge config) and to check for auth pages and such, but even with everything commented out, it makes the 404 page constantly refresh itself

middleware.ts:

```js
import { getToken } from "next-auth/jwt";
import { withAuth } from "next-auth/middleware";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import type { NextRequest } from "next/server";
import { get } from "@vercel/edge-config";

export const config = {
    matcher: ["/((?!_next|icon.svg|favicon.ico|api).*)"]
};

export default withAuth(
    async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
        // if (process.env.EDGE_CONFIG && process.env.NODE_ENV !== "development") {
        //  if (req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/maintenance")) return null;
        //  const isInMaintenanceMode = await get("isInMaintenanceMode");
        //  console.log("isInMaintenanceMode", isInMaintenanceMode);
        //  if (isInMaintenanceMode) {
        //      return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/maintenance", req.url));
        //  }
        // }

        // if (req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/dashboard") || req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/login") || req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/register")) {
        //  console.log("matches")
        //  const token = await getToken({ req });
        //  const isAuth = !!token;
        //  const isAuthPage = req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/login") || req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/register");

        //  if (isAuthPage) {
        //      if (isAuth) {
        //          return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/dashboard", req.url));
        //      }

        //      return null;
        //  }

        //  if (!isAuth) {
        //      let from = req.nextUrl.pathname;
        //      if (req.nextUrl.search) {
        //          from += req.nextUrl.search;
        //      }

        //      return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(`/login?callbackUrl=${encodeURIComponent(from)}`, req.url));
        //  }
        // }
    },
    {
        callbacks: {
            async authorized() {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
);
```

i have tried to comment out the middleware (which had no effect on the error)
and i have also made the matcher only target one page, which worked, however i need it to target all pages so that the middleware function works